# What resources are used on a local Oracle database when a query is executed against a linked database?

Tags: oracle, performance, hyperlink, resources

I am writing an application in C# that will execute queries against a local and linked databases (all Oracle 10g and newer), and I want to make sure I understand who is doing what when a linked database is being queried.

For example, for a simple query such as

`SELECT * FROM FOO@DB_LINK`

What is the local database server responsible for?  I assume that this will use the CPU, disk, and memory on the database server that hosts `DB_LINK`, but what impact does this query have on the local database server resources?

What if the query is a little more complex, such as

`SELECT * FROM FOO@DB_LINK F INNER JOIN BAR@DB_LINK B ON F.FOOBAR = B.FOOBAR`

Is the entire query executed on the server that hosts `DB_LINK`, or is the `INNER JOIN` performed on the local server?  If the `INNER JOIN` is performed by the local database, is it able to utilize the indexes that are on the linked tables (I wouldn't think so)?  Is there a way to tell Oracle to execute the entire query on the linked database?

In my application, my queries will always be completely against either the local database, or a selected linked database.  In other words, I will never have a query where I am getting data from both the local and a linked database at the same time like

`SELECT * FROM FOO F INNER JOIN BAR@DB_LINK B ON F.FOOBAR = B.FOOBAR`

To summarize,

1. I am only dealing with Oracle 10g or newer databases.
2. What is the local database server responsible for when a query (however complex) is strictly against linked tables?
3. What are the ways (if any) to optimize or give Oracle hints about how to best execute these kinds of queries? (examples in C# would be great)

Comment: The Oracle Database Administrator's Guide talks about this a bit in [Chapter 32.4 Tuning Distributed Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/developing-applications-for-a-distributed-database-system.html#GUID-40CD4112-BCA0-4BF9-8EB7-313069531009)

Comment: Thanks @kfinity, however the extent of the documentation is "The local Oracle Database server breaks the distributed query into a corresponding number of remote queries, which it then sends to the remote nodes for execution. The remote nodes execute the queries and send the results back to the local node. The local node then performs any necessary post-processing and returns the results to the user or application." How does Oracle determine where to break the distributed query into remote queries?  Is it smart enough to determine that a query against all remote objects can be passed entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Like most things related to the optimizer, it depends.

If you generate a query plan for a particular query, the query plan will tell you what if anything the local database is doing and which operations are being done on the remote database.  Most likely, if statistics on the objects are reasonably accurate and the query references only objects in a single remote database, the optimizer will be smart enough to push the entire query to the remote server to execute.

Alas, the optimizer is not always going to be smart enough to do the right thing.  If that happens, you can most likely resolve it by adding an appropriate `driving_site` hint to the query.

```
SELECT /*+ driving_site(F) */ * 
  FROM FOO@DB_LINK F 
       INNER JOIN BAR@DB_LINK B 
          ON F.FOOBAR = B.FOOBAR
```

Depending on how complex the queries are, how difficult it is to add hints to your queries, and how much difficulty you have in your environment getting the optimizer to behave, creating views in the remote database can be another way to force queries to run on the remote database.  If you create a view on `db_link` that joins the two tables together and query that view over the database link, that will (in my experience) always force the execution to happen on the remote database where the view is defined.  I wouldn't expect this option to be needed given the fact that you aren't mixing local and remote objects but I include it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

A 100% remote query will get optimized by the remote instance. The local instance will still need to allocate some memory and use CPU in order to fetch results from the remote server but the main work (things like hash joins and looping) will all be done by the remote instance.

When this happens, you will get a note in your local execution plan

```
Note
-----
   - fully remote statement
```

As soon as something is required to be done on the local server (e.g an insert or if you join to a local table (including local dual))  as part of the statement, then the query becomes distributed, only one server can be considered the driving site and it will typically be local (I can't come up with a demo where this chooses the remote site, even when it's cheaper so maybe it's not cost based). Typically this will end up with you hitting some badness somewhere - perhaps a nested loop join against remote tables computed on the local side.

One thing to keep in mind with distributed queries - the optimizing instance will not look at histogram information from the other instance.